# Get all Data in a Body using Guzzle in Laravel from External API

Tags: php, laravel

I want to retrieve only the email in a JSON response using guzzle in Laravel from an external API. Here is what I have tried

```
//Get all customer 
$allcus = 'https://api.paystack.co/customer';
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', $allcus, [
  'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.'sk_live_#########################',
  ],
]); 

$cus_data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents()); 
//returns a json response of all customers
//dd($cus_data);

$cus_data_email = $cus_data->data->email;
dd($cus_data_email);
```

Using this returns error

```
$cus_data_email = $cus_data->data->email;
```

> "message": "Trying to get property 'email' of non-object"

But when I tried this, it returns the customer in the first array

```
$cus_data_email = $cus_data->data[0]->email;
```

I don't want to return just one customer email. I want to retrieve all of the customers' emails.

---

This is the way the JSON response is

```
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "Customers retrieved",
  "data": [
    {
      "integration": ######,
      "first_name": null,
      "last_name": null,
      "email": "a###$gmail.com",
      "phone": null,
      "metadata": null,
      "domain": "live",
      "customer_code": "CUS_##########",
      "risk_action": "default",
      "id": #######,
      "createdAt": "2020-05-26T00:50:12.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-05-26T00:50:12.000Z"
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [loop](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp)!

`$cus_data->data` is an [array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp), which is a variable that can store multiple values at once. These can be accessed with an index, and are commonly seen with loops.

I highly suggest reading the two links I supplied, the loop I'll be using is a `foreach` loop, as it's the most readable in this context. All the loops have their place, so it would pay to get familiar with them.

```
$emailsArray = []; // initialise an array
$emailsString = ""; // initialise a string

// Here's our loop, which will go over all the values of $cus_data->data
foreach($cus_data->data as $datum) {

    // $datum is the single value in $cus_data->data which we're currently looking at
    // Each of these values have an email property, which we access with arrow notation

    array_push($emailsArray, $datum->email); // add the email to our array
    $emailsString = $emailsString . $datum->email . ", "; // add the email to our string

}
```

Following this, `$emailsArray` will be an array (like we learned about above!) with all the emails from `$cus_data->data`.

`$emailsString` will contain the same information, just in a comma-separated string.

One thing to watch out for is if some of your data doesn't have emails! Then the code above could fail.

Admittedly, this isn't the shortest solution. For a problem like this, I would probably use [array_map](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp). The code here does the same thing in a more verbose format so we can understand it better.